# Set "human" app name for facebook app

Tags: settings, facebook-apps

I have created a Facebook app that is accessible at https://apps.facebook.com/12345678 , but I only have a URL with a cryptic app id. Where can I set a name for the app so that I have a nice URL like https://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can  :)

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/summary
2. Edit the "App Namespace" field.
3. Save